# Create video in multiple frames using actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

How to create video from embed images and audio in multiple frame with different framerate using ActionScript3.

What I did was

1. I created the video using layers,but it created one frame for whole video.
2. And when I converted the .swf to .mp4 through converter then the generated .swf was not converted properly.